# Calculate distance between FirebaseVisionText.Element

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I am using `FirebaseVisionText` for reading data from a picture. Any word recognized is stored in a `FirebaseVisionText.Element`. It has same methods like:

- `getBoundingBox()`: Returns the axis-aligned bounding rectangle of the detected text.
- `getCornerPoints()`: Gets the four corner points in clockwise direction starting with top-left.

I would like to calculate the distance between each element recognized. In other words, the distance between the first corner of each element's box.

For example:

```
elementOne.getBoundingBox() -> Rect(1297, 2190 - 1608, 2282)
elementTwo.getBoundingBox() -> Rect(1378, 1772 - 1639, 1860)

distance = sqrt((1297-1378)^2 + (2190-1772)^2) = 425
```